# Highcharts boost rendering extra points at bottom while zoomed

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-boost

I've created a Highcharts scatter graph with X-Y points that are arranged in a grid-like pattern, alternating between even and odd positions.

While using the boost module, I am seeing extra points being rendered at the bottom of the chart when zoomed in.

[image]

Not sure what to do about it. The extra points do no appear to have events attached to them and I can't seem to hide them any other way.

I suspect this may be a bug with the boost module, because the erroneous points are not plotted when the boost module is not being used.

```js
// Prepare the data
var data = [],
    n = 100,
    i;
for (x = 0; x < n; x += 1) {
    for (y = 0; y < n; y += 1) {
        if (x % 2 === y % 2)
        continue
      data.push([x, y])
  }
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        height: '100%',
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var x = this.xAxis[0]
            var y = this.yAxis[0]
            x.setExtremes(18, 23)
            y.setExtremes(44, 52)
          }
        }
    },

    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true,
        usePreAllocated: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        gridLineWidth: 1
    },

    yAxis: {
        // Renders faster when we don't have to compute min and max
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        color: 'magenta',
        data: data,
        marker: {
            radius: 3
        },
        tooltip: {
            followPointer: false,
            pointFormat: '[{point.x:.1f}, {point.y:.1f}]'
        }
    }]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff Jenkins, It is a Highcharts bug and I see that you have already reported it on Highcharts GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/17844 The problem was also reported previously here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13170

Comment: @ppotaczek Yeah I was getting low visibility on SO, so I figured I'd make an issue. I tried searching, but must not have searched hard enough, so thanks for sharing the existing issue. I'll be sure to follow the progress on that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It looks like your dataset might not work well with the useGPUTranslations ([API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/boost.useGPUTranslations)).

> Please, for this specific dataset, do not use this option- [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xh0c6mgq/).
> An explanation of why this is recommended in this case in the API.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  boost: {
    //  useGPUTranslations: true,
    usePreAllocated: true
  },
  // ...
})
```